# Is there any way to deserialize a nonstandard JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

```
{
"id":1,
"city":"cityname",
"address":"{"name":"addressName"}"
}
```

for example
The value of the address field is missing an escape,Is there a way to deserialize it as a string

Comment: In the eyes of a JSON parser this is simply invalid JSON. So you probably need to post-process the received data, write your own parser (*not recommended*) or the data source needs to conform to the specification and produce valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and No.

- Yes:

  - If there is a reliable pattern for detecting the error, you could *potentially* write some Java code to insert the missing escapes.  Then you parse the corrected JSON using a regular JSON parser.
  - It might even be possible to write a custom JSON parser that treats a `"{"` sequence as `"{\"`, and so on.  Or modify an existing parser to do that.
- No: A regular JSON parser will reject this.  AFAIK, no mainstream JSON parser supports arbitrary non-standard (i.e. broken!) JSON variants.

A better idea is to fix whatever is generating the broken JSON.  Or charge the customer who wants you to support this garbage a **LOT OF MONEY** because their data doesn't conform to the agreed requirements.  (Assuming that the agreed requirements said JSON.)